# Angular Service Worker Detect Cache Completed

Tags: service-worker, angular7, angular-service-worker, service-worker-events

I'm Using Angular service worker for offline caching, Most of the time the app will be used in offline mode only, so on initial app launch i want to display '**Application ready to use**' snack bar once the caching is completed, to make sure all the background caching is completed and the application is fully ready to take offline. Is there an option to detect the caching complete process? because i couldn't find anything in the official documentation and googling also didn't help.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue?

Comment: Still looking for a way to do this! It seems like it should not be that difficult for someone familiar with the internals of the angular service worker.